# VSCode debug can't show reference value

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, vscode-debugger

When I debug in vs code, I can't see the reference type value but an address, how can it show the referenced objected value in the debug window?

[image]

Comment: While not really an answer to your question, a workaround would be to use `println!("{}", std::any::type_name::<T>())`

Comment: Thank you, but I still want to do it in a more elegant way, hard-coded seems a little bit of trouble.

Comment: Interesing, I stumbled upon this as well and never thought about it. I am currently reading the source of the lldb extension, and actually it **should** work and display the array slice correctly! There exists Code for this purpose, maybe its a bug. Will investigate it.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

This seems to be a regex matching bug in vscode-lldb. A fix is already in master, so everyone who can be patient just has to wait. To fix this immediately edit `/home/$user$/.vscode-oss/extensions/vadimcn.vscode-lldb-1.6.0/formatters/rust.py`.

Go to line 39 and find:

`attach_synthetic_to_type(SliceSynthProvider, r'^&(mut\s*)?\[.*\]$', True)`

Replace the line with:

`attach_synthetic_to_type(SliceSynthProvider, r'^&(mut[[:space:]]*)?\[.*\]$', True)`

See the related commit as to why this happens:

https://github.com/vadimcn/vscode-lldb/commit/ad084125ab8f749f534b889261d1fe1789467630

Old answer:

You can use formatting to achieve this. Add the following into the watch window, to view the pointer as an array of length 5:

```
arr.data_ptr,[5]
```

See the docs, for further formatting options:
https://github.com/vadimcn/vscode-lldb/blob/v1.6.0/MANUAL.md#formatting

Comment: However, I have replaced the python code in the extension, but it still shows an address value instead of a referenced object's value.